# simplest and most concise form to write a property in C#9 and c#10

Tags: c#, properties, c#-9.0, c#-10.0

What is the simplest and most concise form to write a property as follows, considering the features of C#9 or even C#10?

Is it possible without using the backing field?

```
string fName;
public string Name { get { return fName; } set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(Name), ref fName, value); } }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public string Name {get;}
```

Should be the simplest you can do.

If you need support for WPFs PropertyChanged I usually do

```
private string name;
public string Name {get => name; set => Set(ref name, value); }
private void Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName]string caller = "")
{
    field = value;
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller ));
}
```

Optionally add a comparison inside the Set method to only raise the event if the new value is not equal to the old value. As far as I know there is nothing new in c# 9 or 10 that improves this.

Comment: Is it possible without using the backing field?

(SetPropertyValue is a method in DevExpress)

Comment: @Roohi No, because auto implemented properties just create a backing field for you that you don't see and you cannot change the `set` to use that backing field while adding additional code (without using some hacky reflection code).

Comment: I wonder if you can make an extension method on `T value` and call it like `value.Set(ref field);`.

Comment: @Roohi as far as I know, no. There is no way to write an auto-property while raising PropertyChanged. It would have been nice if there where, but that might introduce a tighter coupling between the language and WPF than the language designers want.

Comment: Just I read this article, now. 
C# 10 - Semi-Auto Properties and 'field' Keyword

https://exceptionnotfound.net/bite-size-csharp-10-semi-auto-properties-using-field-keyword/

Is that right?

Comment: @Roohi as the article mentions that feature did not seem to make the cut for c# 10. See [c#10 new features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10)